# How to get the path to a node

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I'm using a view template to override how a field is displayed.

I want to include a link to the node in the field.

Given a node, how do I get the URL (relative is fine) for a node?

I've got the node in the overridden template, but not sure where to go from there:

```
$node = node_load($row->{$field->field_alias});
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

$path_to_node = ???

?><a href="<?php print $path_to_node ?>">Go to Node</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need entity_metadata_wrapper in this case.
You can get path of node using `url()` function.

```
$node = node_load($row->{$field->field_alias}); 
$nid = $node->nid; 
$path_to_node = url("node/$nid");
```

And I agree with Елин Й's answer. You can use `l()` function. It already uses `url()` function. So you can build link with node pathauto alias using:

```
$node = node_load($row->{$field->field_alias}); 
print l(t('Go to Node'), 'node/' . $node->nid);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you need to output the Node: Path field. Then you can access the information in the view using:

```
$fields["path"]->content;
```

Answer (score 0):

A views template should have the $view variable available, so you could use:

```
$nid = $view->result[$id]->nid;
$path = "node/".$nid;
```

Answer (score 0):

URL to a node is `node/$node->nid`. I would strongly recommend you to use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function to generate links, so that it will always print the right URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example it would be:

```
$node = node_load($row->{$field->field_alias});
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
print l(t('Go to Node'), 'node/' . $node->nid);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a proper seo friendly url use the lookup path function:

$ path = drupal_lookup_path('alias',"node/".$node->nid)